# variable lengths differ (found for 'EMI')

Tags: r, regression, binning

I'm getting this error "variable lengths differ ". Please suggest me how to solve it . there are no Gas in data set

```
## Binning DV
y <- cut (df$Driving_hours_day,3,include.lowest = TRUE, 
labels = c("Moderate","High","Very high"))
y
summary(y)
str(y)

## Convert DV to ordinal variable
cat_y <- as.ordered(y)
str(cat_y)
summary(cat_y)

##partition data
ind <- sample(2, nrow(df), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.8,0.2))
train <- df[ind ==1,]
test <- df[ind ==2,]

# 3. Ordinal Logitic Regression or Proportional Odds Logistic regression
library(MASS)
names(df)
any(is.na(df))
model <- polr(cat_y~  EMI + HH_income + driving_years + current_veh_usage,
data = train, Hess = TRUE)
summary(model)
```

Comment: do I need to. standardise the other variables ?

Comment: Questions about how to do things in R (or any software) are off topic here.  But you almost certainly shouldn't be binning your DV at all. That throws away information and increasses Type 1 and Type 2 error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to split your y variable into train and test as well.

Specifically at this step:

```
cat_y <- as.ordered(y)
ind$cat_y <- cat_y

##partition data
ind <- sample(2, nrow(df), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.8,0.2))
train <- df[ind ==1,]
test <- df[ind ==2,]
```

Then you regress again:

```
library(MASS)
model <- polr(cat_y~  EMI + HH_income + driving_years + current_veh_usage,
data = train, Hess = TRUE)
```